# Bridge Swift 4 enum to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

**EDIT:** I apologize all of you, this was all the time my fault - it wasn't possible even in Swift 3. I confused myself big time. Sorry for this question.

Apparently bridging array of enum values to Objective C is no longer possible in Swift 4, not even using @objc annotation:

```
@objc open func removeCacheAfterDelay(_ delay: Double, forType types: [CacheManagerType]) {
}

@objc public enum CacheManagerType: Int, RawRepresentable {
    case credit
    case debit
    case transactionHistory
}
```

Following error is displayed at the *removeCacheAfterDelay* function:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2
>   cannot be represented in Objective-C

Am I missing something? Is there any workaround?

Comment: The problem is the array, not the enum.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but is there any way to make it work? This method as is worked fine in Swift 3 when bridged into ObjC even with this array...

Comment: I think that was because the nature of bridging was different in Swift 3.

Comment: So does that mean it will simply not work in Swift 4 no more? What about some workaround? I have plenty of swift enum arrays bridged to ObjC in my app...

Comment: Make them `[Int]` arrays and map the enums to their raw values. That works because the Ints are mapped to NSNumber, which is an object.

Comment: Are you sure that this worked in Swift 3? I get the identical error message for your code in Xcode 8.3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to think like Objective-C. What could this declaration possibly mean when translated into Objective-C? In particular, what would `[CacheManagerType]` mean? It would have to be an array, i.e. an NSArray, containing CacheManagerType objects.

But that's impossible. CacheManagerType is an enum. An Int enum bridged to Objective-C is turned into an Objective-C enum. For your method declaration to work in Objective-C, Objective-C would need to be able to understand the concept of an array of enums — and it doesn't. In Objective-C, an enum is not an object, but an NSArray can hold only objects.

Comment: "But that's impossible" - but according to the OP it worked in Swift 3. Looking at your comment on the question you say `[Int]` works in Swift 4, but here you could have written "In Objective-C, an *Int* is not an object, but an NSArray can hold only objects". So your answer is inconsistent with both your comment and apparently denies the reality of Swift 3... Maybe tidy this up?